# How to apply block transforms for a block with innerBlocks?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to create my first block (using wp-create-block). It is a "factbox" block and would mostly work as a group block, except that it always is an aside, supports float (left and right), and will be collapsable.

I've managed to create the block, it works, but I can't get block transforms to work. I read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-transforms/), tried to copy code from the core/group-block, but I can't my code to work.

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps, __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps,
useInnerBlocksProps as useInnerBlocksProps, AlignmentToolbar } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import './editor.scss';

const Edit = () => {
const blockProps = useBlockProps();
const settings = {
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: 'block',
            isMultiBlock: true,
            blocks: [ '*' ],
            __experimentalConvert( blocks ) {
                
                // Clone the Blocks to be Grouped
                // Failing to create new block references causes the original blocks
                // to be replaced in the switchToBlockType call thereby meaning they
                // are removed both from their original location and within the
                // new group block.
                const groupInnerBlocks = blocks.map( ( block ) => {
                    return createBlock(
                        block.name,
                        block.attributes,
                        block.innerBlocks
                    );
                } );

                return createBlock(
                    'wp-create-block/factbox',
                    groupInnerBlocks
                );
            },
        },
    ]
    }
};


return (
    <aside { ...blockProps }>
        <InnerBlocks defaultBlock={['core/paragraph', {placeholder: "Lorem ipsum..."}]} directInsert />
    </aside>
);
};
export default Edit;
```

I don't get any error messages, but I don't get the option to transform any blocks into my block either?

Expected behaviour is that I'm able to select one or more blocks and transform them into a factbox, like I can do with a group.

Comment: I see that you've created a new `settings` object similar to the documentation but it isn't used anywhere, is there code missing from your question? The settings object it's referring to in the documentation is the settings object used to register the block, not a new separate settings object in your edit component. I also see there is lots of missing or incorrect indentation making it very difficult to read, can you fix that using the edit link?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell

That was it. I should add the code in index.js where the block is registered, not in the edit.js. 

Though, I still get errors, as the my block now causes an unexpected error in the editor, but it transformation shows up in the expected place. 

I don't know why you can't see the indentation in the code, it looks fine on my end here.